# Spring Boot Issue using MapStruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am new to Spring Boot. I hope someone will help me understand what i am doing wrong.

I created service.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor 
@Service
public class UserService {
    
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    public UserDto login(CredentialDto credentialDto) {
        User user = userRepository.findBylogin(credentialDto.login())
            .orElseThrow(()-> {
            ApplicationException ex =new ApplicationException();
            ex.setMessage("Unknown user");
            return ex;
        });
        return userMapper.toUserDto(user);
    }
}
```

My Mapper class is:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
    UserDto toUserDto(User user);
}
```

I got error in IDE which is given below:

**Description:**

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.example.jwttest.service.UserService required a bean of type 'com.example.jwttest.mappers.UserMapper' that could not be found.
```

**Action:**

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.jwttest.mappers.UserMapper' in your configuration.
```

Greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi, could you provide your pom.xml and packages of classes? Anyway seems like UserMapper isn't found as Bean to instantiate from Spring. You could try to add a `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = UserMapper.class)` into your Application class or move `UserMapper` in a subpackage of Application class

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
   <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0.Beta1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Can you provide information about how do you run this code? What IDE are you using Eclipse or Intellij IDEA? What build tool are you using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: issue was I didn't use mapstruct processor. 
                 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
   <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
   <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
  </dependency> 

        also in properties on pom.
          <properties>
 
  <mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</mapstruct.version>
 
 </properties>

Answer (score 1):

Probably you didn't have configured well:

apart from dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

you need to configure also the maven-compiler-plugin

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.0</version>
     <configuration>
         <annotationProcessorPaths>
             <path>
                 <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                 <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                 <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
             </path>
             <path>
                 <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                 <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                 <version>${lombok.version}</version>
             </path>
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                 <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                 <version>0.2.0</version>
             </dependency>
         </annotationProcessorPaths>
         <compilerArgs>
             <compilerArg>
                 -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
             </compilerArg>
         </compilerArgs>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

check this Step-By-Step tutorial: [springframework.guru/mapstruct](https://springframework.guru/using-mapstruct-with-project-lombok/)

Comment: OMG. I forget maven-compiler-plugin. Many Thanks Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at my mini project on GitHub which demonstrates the integration of MapStruct with Spring https://github.com/youssefehaab/java-mapstruct/tree/v1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to clean first use `mvn clean` command if you use maven.